# How to move a file to another directory and change the content of it using pipe in one line in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, pipeline, powershell-cmdlet

Below code does not work. But doing them seperately in two line works.

Move-Item file.txt \same-directory | Set-Content -Path \same-directoy -Value "New content"

Comment: Why are you looking [for a oneliner](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)?

Comment: No reason. Just curiosity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Move-Item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/move-item?view=powershell-6#outputs) cmdlet without switch `-PassThru` returns nothing, so in that case, nothing gets sent through the pipe to the `Set-Content` cmdlet.

If you really want to do this as one-liner, use

```
Move-Item -Path 'D:\file.txt' -Destination 'D:\some-directory' -PassThru | Set-Content -Value "New content"
```

Since now we're actually piping the moved object, the `-Path` parameter for the `Set-Content` needs to be omitted.

<sup>Of course, the destination folder `D:\some-directory` needs to exist</sup>